# Express.js Catch All routing not working on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, routes

I am trying to setup Express.js routing and I have run into a problem that I don't understand.

I am setting up a catch all route like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('CAUGHT HOME');
  res.render('../public/index.ejs');
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  console.log('CAUGHT ALL');
  res.render('../public/index.ejs');
});
```

Running Node.js locally on Windows 7, prints the console log messages when I make requests to any URL, so everything is setup correctly.

However, when I upload my script to AWS EC2, and make the requests, the console messages are not printed.

I have another route that works perfectly on both locally and on AWS, setup like this:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

        res.render('../public/login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
    });
```

I don't understand why the routing does work, but not for the catch all.
Are there any system settings that need to be changed to get the catch all to work? Or is there something else I am doing incorrectly?

I would very much appreciate any suggestions! TIA!

This is a snippet the local console output where everything is working as expected:

```
CAUGHT HOME
GET / 304 25ms
CAUGHT ALL
GET /font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css 200 5ms - 2.32kb
CAUGHT ALL
GET /css/bootstrap.min.css 200 2ms - 2.32kb
CAUGHT ALL
GET /css/animate.css 200 1ms - 2.32kb
CAUGHT ALL
GET /css/style.css 200 1ms - 2.32kb
CAUGHT ALL
GET /js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js 200 6ms - 2.32kb
CAUGHT ALL
GET /js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js 200 2ms - 2.32kb
CAUGHT ALL
GET /js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js 200 1ms - 2.32kb
```

And this is the console output on AWS:

```
GET / 304 39ms
GET /font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css 304 111ms
GET /css/bootstrap.min.css 304 52ms
GET /js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js 304 50ms
GET /css/animate.css 304 51ms
GET /css/style.css 304 53ms
GET /js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js 304 58ms
GET /js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js 304 13ms
```

Comment: d'you get `CAUGHT ALL` on your local machine even when requesting `/`? You'd normally have to call `next()` to get this behaviour..

Comment: yes, when I access the site locally (http://localhost:8100) the console message "CAUGHT HOME" and "CAUGHT ALL" are printed. "CAUGHT ALL" is printed for each of the js/css/img files. "CAUGHT HOME" is printed once. On AWS none of the messages are printed

Answer (score 0):

Try out like this:

```
app.route('/*')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    // 
  });
```

Comment: I tried that, still not printing the console message on AWS

Answer (score 0):

The problem was really confusing me, because some of the routing was working and some not.

I decided to delete all the files on my server and re-upload the entire site, and this resolved the issue.